# Mongo DB authentication not working in grails but from console

Tags: mongodb, grails

I want to use authentication in my mongodb. So I created a user. Which this user I can connect on command line and insert data without any problem.

But when I want to use this user in grails, I get this error:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18 , "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed"}
```

When I connect from commandline, everything works:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "mongouser" -p "pwd" mydb
```

My code in Grails:

```
 MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential("mongouser", "mydb", "pwd".toCharArray())
 def mongoClient = new MongoClient( new ServerAddress(host, port), [credential ] )
 gMongoCon = new GMongo(mongoClient)
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works:

```
MongoCredential.createCredential(username, datatable, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your mongo credentials in Config.groovy or external config as follows,

```
grails
        {

                mongo
                {
                    host            =   "YOUR_HOST_NAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS" // e.g localhost
                    port            =   27017
                    username        =   "mongouser" //Username
                    password        =   "pwd"       //password
                    databaseName    =   "mydb" //Database name
                }
        }
```

> Note: change the bind_ip from /etc/mongod.conf if the application and
>   mongo are on different server.

Comment: I got the same exception. I created the connection with new GMongo() without any parameters. Is this okay?

Comment: No need to use GMongo, keep that simple as above, did you try above code? restarted app?

Comment: I don't want to use mongo db for domains, I want to use mongo db with GMongo

Comment: ok, so you have the variables host and port passed to serviceAddress right?

Comment: I connected with MongoCredential like I described in my post

Comment: You should have the values for host and port declared in variable

Comment: I have the values for host and port declared in a variable

Comment: Connect is okay, put when I use a insert() exception is thrown like I mentionend in my post